# Silverlight 4 OOB White Screen of Death. Failed to load pre-requisites for the application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

I'm developing a SL4 OOB application that has suddenly started giving me the white screen of death.

If I try to run it 'in-browser' and check the console I can see the error 2105 : 'Failed to load pre-requisites for the application' but there's very little info about it anywhere.

None of my breakpoints get hit.  Even starting the app with F11 (step into) doesn't get me anywhere.

I can run other Silverlight projects just fine so it's not the runtime.  I've even copied the source into another project to see if that might help but to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might get started fixing this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the Startup Object in the Project Properties is still pointing to the correct Application class? I something similar to happen to me a while back when I refactored the namespaces in my project and somehow this was not picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn it, I hate answering my own questions but the problem was quite obscure.

Somehow, I managed to get a regular .Net reference in my Silverlight project through a Nuget package.  That was it.

DOH!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this myself and it was a pain..

What I had to do was a system restore, de-installed all traces of Silverlight and Blend and then reinstalled them all. However I had also just installed Silverlight 5 RC which didn't play nicely with Telerik and might have been the problem.

There is also some information about this error here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/530074/unhandled-error-in-silverlight-application-2105-when-building-as-an-x86-configuration.

Is this your problem?